# Net Core Middleware acting on failed requirements

Tags: asp.net-core, authorization, asp.net-authorization

Using Core 3.1

Have an authorization handler that gets invoked through an authorization filter (i.e. effects all controllers):

```
var builder = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder();
builder.Requirements.Add(new MySpecialRequirement(...));
var policy = builder.Build();

services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, MySpecialAuthorizeHandler>();

services
  .AddControllers(options => options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy)))
  .AddControllersAsServices();
```

When the handler doesn't call succeed on then the filter fails returning a standard 403 without a response message.  Is it possible from Core Middleware to see what requirements failed?  If possible then the response message could be adjusted correspondingly.  This would also open for looking at the collection of requirements that didn't pass rather than a specific.

Comment: `Is it possible from Core Middleware to see what requirements failed?` Can you clarify more about your requirement? so that we can understand it better.

Comment: The response message can't be written to from an inbound filter.  If the authorization requirements can be accessed from Middleware (outbound) then the response message could be edited in respect to which requirements failed or succeeded.